# #1054 - Unknown column 'wp_usermeta.meta_key' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I've been breaking my head on a SQL-query that stopped working for me. I have the following query:

```
SELECT count(ID) AS total FROM `wp_users` WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'wp_capabilities' AND (`meta_value` LIKE '%overleden%' || `meta_value` LIKE '%oudlid%' || `meta_value` LIKE '%adverteerder%')) AND ((wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'plaats' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%michiel%') OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'achternaam' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%michiel%') OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'roepnaam' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%michiel%'))
```

What am I doing wrong? The code should give me a count on users with the name "michiel".

Kind regards,
Michiel

Answer (score 0):

Table name wp_usermeta is in WHERE subquery, and you can't use it in other conditions.

Comment: That you for your reply. Is there a way to make it possible to use it in other conditions?

Comment: You may need rewrite using JOIN.

Comment: Ah, that did the trick! Thanks for the push in the right direction :)